# NIO2 and charset used in channels

Tags: java, character-encoding, channel

When I read this string with NIO2 channels:

```
È bla bla bla
```

I get this in my console:

```
? bla bla bla
```

I was wondering how can I set the charset, when the code is something like this:

```
RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("in.txt", "rw");
FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();

ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);

int bytesRead = inChannel.read(buf);
while (bytesRead != -1) {

  System.out.println("Read " + bytesRead);
  buf.flip();

  while(buf.hasRemaining()){
      System.out.print((char) buf.get());
  }

  buf.clear();
  bytesRead = inChannel.read(buf);
}
aFile.close();
```

I would like to set something like this:

```
StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your code you are reading bytes from a FileChannel. How you will interpret those bytes is up to you.

In your code the read bytes are converted to a string when you do `System.out.print((char) buf.get());`. This is why you see that output.

Try to create explicitly a new `String` using the [contructor that specifies the desired character set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) i.e. `String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you are correct. Wrong copy-paste. I have edited my answer. Thanks